# Pygame, move a rectangle and remove the old rectangle in precedent position

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame, draw, rect

I'm writing this code because I want to move a rectangle using the arrow keys.
It works, but the loop cycle doesn't move the rectangle, instead it creates a new one every time. The result is like a contrail. You can see it in the pic:[the result of the code after some key pressure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXzZx.png)

Here the code I wrote:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('SAGA')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
FPS=30
#the initial position
POS_X=300
POS_Y=300
ship = pygame.image.load("fighter_0.png")

while True:
    #if cycle for detect the key pressure
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_UP:
                POS_Y=POS_Y-10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_DOWN:
                POS_Y=POS_Y+10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                POS_X=POS_X+10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_LEFT:
                POS_X=POS_X-10
    #here i draw the rectangle 
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(POS_X,POS_Y,30,30))
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

I think I don't understand some principle of pygame, but honestly I don't know which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you told it to do: draw a new rectangle each time.  Computers are frustrating that way.  You used **draw** instead of moving an object.

To fix this, you have two basic alternatives:

1. In each iteration, first obliterate the previous rectangle with one that matches the background (black).  *Then* draw the new rectangle.
2. Use a movable object, such as a sprite, and update your game with the **move** method instead of redrawing.  If you search StackOverflow or the internet for "pygame move object" you'll likely find a lot of code you can adapt for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you run your loop, you draw over the old screen's image. So in your case you are drawing rectangles on top of the previous rectangles. You need to clear the screen of what was there on the previous iteration of the loop. The easiest way to do this is to fill the screen with a single colour or image:

```
import sys
import pygame

# Colours
black = [0, 0, 0]

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption('SAGA')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
FPS=30
#the initial position
POS_X=300
POS_Y=300
ship = pygame.image.load("fighter_0.png")

while True:
    #if cycle for detect the key pressure
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_UP:
                POS_Y=POS_Y-10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_DOWN:
                POS_Y=POS_Y+10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                POS_X=POS_X+10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_LEFT:
                POS_X=POS_X-10
    #here i draw the rectangle 
    screen.fill(black) # Fill the entire screen with black
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(POS_X,POS_Y,30,30))
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```